# Sqoop import from Intersystems Caché

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, intersystems-cache

I'm trying to set up a **Sqoop import** to pull a query from **Intersystems** Caché into a **Hive table**; I've managed to connect, but the job fails some 2 minutes after the mapping phase starts, with a connection timeout message.
I'll provide both the sqoop job and the messages below:

```
 sqoop import 
-Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/user/bigdata/myCachePWD.password.jceks
--connect jdbc:Cache://server:1972/database   
--username my_username   
--password-alias myCachePWD.password.alias   
--table sds.T00055_PCTE      
--hive-database stg_splunk  
--hive-table t00055_pcte   
--hive-overwrite 
--hive-import 
--num-mappers 10   
--as-parquetfile   
--compress 
--compression-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec    
--warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse/stage/    
--driver com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver 
--split-by DT_ICLO
```

And here is the relevant error log:

> 19/12/30 16:24:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for
>   job: job_1577368744752_0394 19/12/30 16:24:15 INFO
>   impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application
>   application_1577368744752_0394 19/12/30 16:24:15 INFO mapreduce.Job:
>   The url to track the job:
>   http://[SERVER]:8088/proxy/application_1577368744752_0394/
>   19/12/30 16:24:15 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job:
>   job_1577368744752_0394 19/12/30 16:24:46 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job
>   job_1577368744752_0394 running in uber mode : false 19/12/30 16:24:46
>   INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0% 19/12/30 16:27:25 INFO
>   mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1577368744752_0394_m_000000_0, Status
>   : FAILED Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Cache JDBC]
>   Communication link failure: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out) at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:73)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:755) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158) Caused
>   by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: [Cache JDBC]
>   Communication link failure: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out) at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)
>   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)
>   ... 10 more Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [Cache JDBC]
>   Communication link failure: Connection timed out (Connection timed
>   out) at
>   com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.connect(CacheConnection.java:1063)
>   at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheConnection.(CacheConnection.java:370)
>   at com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver.connect(CacheDriver.java:211) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247) at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)
>   at
>   org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)
>   ... 11 more

I'm not sure if I got the correct driver; I copied the Cache driver from `DBeaver` into `/var/lib/sqoop` and used the `com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver` in the sqoop job; it does connect though, so I'm not sure if it's a driver version issue or some other server side config...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to test the connection using sqoop list-databases or list-tables or eval.
sqoop eval ........ "select count(*) from table".
Also check the logs from the url link of the sqoop output above. (The url to track the job: .......)

Comment: Yes, sqoop eval works from the namenode and one of the worker nodes, but not from the others... that is how I discovered it was a firewall issue. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turned out to be a firewall issue; access was granted only to two machines on our cluster, so when Sqoop sent out the mappers from the other machines to read from Caché, the connection from those nodes was refused.